# Unable to get CiviCRM running on Drupal 8/Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS/Linode

Tags: drupal-8

I have tried following the Roundearth instructions twice to get CiviCRM up and running on a clean install of Drupal 8, on Ubuntu server 18.0.4. First time through, the installer failed with a permissions error but CiviCRM reported as installed—if there's a way of reverting from this situation, I couldn't figure it out, and I ended up having to start over.

Second time through, it all looked good, but going to any CiviCRM page came up blank. Checking PHP errors, it was maxing out memory. So I increased it to 256, 512, and unlimited—each time, it maxed out on memory (3.2 gigs in the case of unlimited, whereas the server has 4), and I gave up and went home. Only to discover when I got there that the pages now loaded, and continued to load with sane memory restrictions. (???) However, there's no CiviCRM menu (it appears to be there, but empty), and when I go to handpasted admin URLs, things that are supposed to be there according to the docs are blank.

Both of these were with the Roundearth instructions—I found a different set [here](https://sevaa.com/blog/2018/08/drupal-crm-integration/) that I'm trying out, but I don't feel good about it.

I have to deploy a staged site by Friday, and if I can't get CiviCRM to work, I'll plow on without it—but I gather that it *really* wants to be installed before I start piling on other modules. Any help *greatly* appreciated.

EDIT: Occurs to me that I have *not* tried installing Drupal from apt-get (if it's there), because the Roundearth composer script had it included. Could try that next before moving on to the linked instructions. *Or not, as apparently it's not in apt.*

Comment: Have you seen the resources at this link: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/wikis/drupal8-composer. I'm not sure about the memory problem but the error log will have a line and file where it's happening and that can give a clue. For the blank admin pages maybe start by checking the javascript console for errors and also check your CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL setting in civicrm.settings.php.

Comment: No, that's all new to me! I'm not sure how to proceed with that page, as there are three different links to HOWTOs, all of them saying "yeah, we need to fix this." I followed the instructions in the first link. Do you suggest I try to hack a solution into the Roundearth install, or try one of the other installation procedures?

Comment: And thank you! —Jeff

Comment: It sounds like you almost got the roundearth one going, and except for the weird memory issues seems like it might just be a matter of having the right settings in civicrm.settings.php and elsewhere which might need manual tweaking after. Your best resource for that is probably the second link (https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes), and just looking in civicrm.settings.php itself.

Comment: Well, you're definitely right that my CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL is borked. In the JavaScript console, there are a thousand errors of the form 404 http://www.mydomain.org//var/www/html/myorg/vendor... What I can't tell is: my site responds to just mydomain.org—so how do I form the BASEURL so it finds the vendor directory? It's at the same level as the web directory.

Comment: Wait, that megaphonetech link is also new to me. Adding those commands now.

Comment: I had to chmod -R the permissions to get the composer script to run. What should they be now? I can see 404s in the JavaScript console to files that are exactly where they should be, and have put dummy html files there to make sure they're served—but the .js files aren't.

Comment: Are they 404's or 403's? i.e. blocked by drupal's .htaccess? Or do you mean the js files aren't physically there, as if they didn't get copied over?

Comment: I can see the files where they should be in the filesystem, and when I moved the helloworld.html dummy file into each nested folder, it served just fine. So I have no idea why the .js files are returning 404—and yes, it's 404 in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Stock Apache install and I'm reasonably decent at Linux, but I'm primarily a Mac guy and I note that all of these files in /web are landing with permissions and owners I'm not used to. (I.e., the Apache install was root/root and I had to chown them to www-data/jporten.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97298/discussion-between-jeff-porten-and-demerit).

Comment: Have moved this discussion to chat as per Stack Exchange notice. Haven't used that before, so FYI if you didn't get a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a combination of adding the settings listed at https://hq.megaphonetech.com/projects/commons/wiki/CiviCRM_for_Drupal_8_installation_notes to  civicrm.settings.php and the file system permissions.

Comment: And fixing some boneheaded mistakes between keyboard and chair on the part of the question author.